# Array to string conversion error when multiple file upload in Laravel 5.8.38

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, multiple-file-upload

I have an **Array to string conversion** error, when trying to realize multiple upload files function in **Laravel 5.8.38**
Cant find any decision about it

In blade form I have simple thing:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('admin.estates.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<label for="estate_image" class="mt-4">Images</label>
<input type="file" name="estate_image[]" multiple>

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
<input type="hidden" name="created_by" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
</form>
```

In store function I have:

The function creates an estate(one property). If user adds some images for it, we adds this images in local path and adds them in database

**if I comment `$estate = Estate::create($request->all());` it works fine**
but in this case estate doesnt adds in database

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $estate = Estate::create($request->all());

    if($request->hasFile('estate_image')) {
        foreach ($request->file('estate_image') as  $image) {

                // do some image resize and store it on local path
                $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $location = public_path('images\\' . $filename);
                Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

                // add image info in database
                $estateimage = new EstateImages();
                $estateimage->image_path = $location;
                $estateimage->image_alt = 'testalt';
                $estateimage->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Am array I have from input

```
array:5 [▼
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "image1.jpg"
    1 => "image2.jpg"
  ]
  "type" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "image/jpeg"
    1 => "image/jpeg"
  ]
  "tmp_name" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "C:\OSPanel\userdata\php_upload\phpCB51.tmp"
    1 => "C:\OSPanel\userdata\php_upload\phpCB52.tmp"
  ]
  "error" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 0
    1 => 0
  ]
  "size" => array:2 [▼
    0 => 164808
    1 => 58217
  ]
]
```

As understand, foreach doesnt start, but dont understand why (tried to delete all code in foreach, and leave there just simple echo 'Hello!'; , have the same error.
Saw the same problems in StackOverflow, but any of it helped me...

Comment: Have you tried using `name="estate_image"` instead of `name="estate_image[]"`?

Comment: kerbh0lz, yes, I tried. In case `name="estate_image" ` it works, but it adds just one image in local path and just one image in database. So its works with just one image, not with the several (multiple) as I need.

Comment: can you show the structure of Estate class fields....you are getting this error because you are getting an array field and it cant be stored in your estates table

Comment: Tanvir Ahmed, you was on right way. Already found it, and writed a solution in post below. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in first line
`$estate = Estate::create($request->all());`

So, from blade I receive `a name="estate_image[]` data which **is an array**, and Laravel tried to adds an array in database cell. In database cell **cold be added just string value** and through that, I had that error.

Solve it, by deleting this column from database and deleting this from `$fillable` variable in main model.

Quite stupid and easy thing from me, but hope, this answer helps someone. :-)